# Destroy link in Rails 3.2 shows the data instead of deleting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding, destroy

I created a new scaffold `rails generate scaffold scores score:integer route_id:integer` and ran `rake db:migrate`.

This works well, but when I go to the scores page to delete some data the delete link somehow displays the view details, but doesn't delete it. I also compared the link with some other projects and it looks pretty much the same only that it doesn't work this time.

That's what I have in my index.html.erb page:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', score, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

I found in some posts on this site that the gem file needs to contain `gem 'jquery-rails'` so I checked and it is there. I also ran `bundle install` again, but no change.
The change from `link_to` to `button_to` didn't help either.

Does anybody have an idea what else it could be? If you need more details let me know and I will be happy to add it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happens because you haven't included jquery_ujs in your application. Ope the browser console and check if jquery_ujs is included or if it is included multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have managed to solve it only after I have added both jquery and jquery_ujs to my page:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery_ujs" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I most probably have a problem with the asset pipelines as I have requested both of them in the application.js but it didn't work when they were not explicitly requested on the page.
In my application.js I have:

```
//= require_jquery
//= require_jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `method: :delete` is being overridden or ignored since you're providing the resource. Could you try this?

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy_score_path(score), data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Here is the documentation for `link_to` for reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried, but it gives me the following error: `undefined method `destroy_score_path' for #<#<Class:0xb58094d0>:0x947ce90>`

Comment: I too guess it will be overwritten by some other function. The question is by what? It worked in the beginning, but then I have done so many things that it is very hard to recall.

Comment: Quick guess: try `destroy_scores_path` (plural). It is possible that you upgraded rails versions and the behavior changed. According the api docs for this method this is only one version where a body can be specified as the first argument and a url (or presumably a model) can be specified as the second argument: link_to(body, url, html_options = {}). In that case the third argument is html_options. I would consider `method: :delete` a url_option. That's why I was thinking it may have been ignored. Could you please post your `routes.rb` and the source code that is generated by your line above?

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
You need to include jquery_ujs also named as rails.js in your application.html.erb.
I have this issue before. Rails needs rails.js to do this.